# Laravel 4: 2 different types of user session

Tags: php, session, laravel, authentication

I am building an app here, it's based on Laravel 4.2.
So user can login and logout. When user is logged in, I wish to keep that session forever so there is no need to re-login every time.

However, there is a search on the website. Search keywords should remain in the search field but should be removed when user closed the browser and left the website.

How can I do this? I know that I need to set cookie, but there is no way in L4 I can have both "expire on close" = true and false.

Answer (score 0):

Well there is a second parameter in `Auth::attempt($credentials, true)`, this allows to keep your user logged-in indefinitely